# when hitting submit the url changes to my php script location

Tags: php, html

So I am coding a simple contact form in php, and when I hit the submit button it runs the code fine on chrome on desktop, however when I hit submit on mobile browsers (and sometimes on desktop) it errors out and the url changes to the location of the script, yet it still submits an email but it being kicked back as spam when it errors out. When it does work my contact form looks fine. Can anyone spot an obvious issue I am missing?

```html
<div class="contact_form">
  <form class="contact_form" action="contactform2.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name..." required>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number..." required>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required>
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..." required>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10" cols="56" placeholder="Message..." required></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    $mail = new PHPmailer;
    $mail->Host='';
    $mail->Port=587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
    $mail->Username='';
    $mail->Password='';
    
    $mail->Setfrom($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
    $mail->addAddress('');
    $mail->addAddress('');
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
    
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject=''.$_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body='<h3 align=left>Name: '.$_POST['name'].'<br><br>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br><br>Telephone: '.$_POST['phone'].'<br><br>Message: '.$_POST['message'].'</h3>';
    
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $result="Something went wrong Please try again.";
    }
    else {
        header("Location: mail_sent.html");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error? "...it errors out and the url chang..."

Comment: So there's no error from the php script just a kickback from the email server saying the email was blocked as spam, when the php script works it redirects to the proper page, when it doesn't I get a blank screen and the url is the location of php script.when script works I get email the correct way in correct format.

Comment: So I figured out what issue was I think, I was entering my email in the contact Form but it was the same one as destination email, once I changed it to a different email address the script works fine. I think the failed delivery causes my script to not finish, is there a way to fix this? Not that it really should be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

This is the code that checks whether the submit parameter exists.